# problems with software center cannot see whats installed

Tags: white-screen

I cant see whats installed,when i select ubuntu software center it comes up white, Oh im a complete newbie, ive moved my laptop from winXP to Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: if you want to see what packages are installed on your Ubuntu pc then run `dpkg --get-selections`.If you had any problems with software-center then run `software-center` command on terminal and post it's output on your question.

Comment: I figured it out by changing some of my colour options, I can now see the screen. Thanks for the help @Avinash Raj